# OpenGL Vertex Array Object(VAO)

Tags: opengl

I have drawn a triangle and a square using open gl and everything was fine.

I have then tried to draw the same triangle and square, while implementing VAO's and now I only get a white triangle - that is not the triangle I am attempting to draw. As far as I can see I am binding everything correctly in the onLoad method.

The square doesnt draw at all. Only the triangle which is not right.

If anyone could point out what I am missing or point me to somewhere I can understand this problem and fix (tutorial or other documentation) I would be very grateful.

Here is the code

```
    using Labs.Utility;
    using OpenTK;
    using OpenTK.Graphics;
    using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
    using System;

    namespace Labs.Lab2
    {
      class Lab2_1Window : GameWindow
      {
    private int[] mVertexArrayObjectIDs = new int[2];

    private int[] mTriangleVertexBufferObjectIDArray = new int[2];
    private int[] mSquareVertexBufferObjectIDArray = new int[2];
    private ShaderUtility mShader;

    public Lab2_1Window()
        : base(
            800, // Width
            600, // Height
            GraphicsMode.Default,
            "Lab 2_1 Linking to Shaders and VAOs",
            GameWindowFlags.Default,
            DisplayDevice.Default,
            3, // major
            3, // minor
            GraphicsContextFlags.ForwardCompatible
            )
    {
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        GL.ClearColor(Color4.CadetBlue);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

        #region Shader Loading Code

        mShader = new ShaderUtility(@"Lab2/Shaders/vLab21.vert", @"Lab2/Shaders/fSimple.frag");

        #endregion

        int vColourLocation = GL.GetAttribLocation(mShader.ShaderProgramID, "vColour");
        int vPositionLocation = GL.GetAttribLocation(mShader.ShaderProgramID, "vPosition");

        //square
        float[] sVertices = new float[]  { -0.2f, -0.4f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.2f,
                                           0.8f, -0.4f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                                           0.8f, 0.6f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.4f,
                                           -0.2f, 0.6f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};

        uint[] sIndices = new uint[] { 0, 1, 2,
        0,3,2};

        GL.GenVertexArrays(2, mVertexArrayObjectIDs);
        GL.BindVertexArray(mVertexArrayObjectIDs[1]);

        GL.GenBuffers(2, mSquareVertexBufferObjectIDArray);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, mSquareVertexBufferObjectIDArray[0]);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(sVertices.Length * sizeof(float)), sVertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        int sSize;
        GL.GetBufferParameter(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, BufferParameterName.BufferSize, out sSize);

        if (sVertices.Length * sizeof(float) != sSize)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Vertex data not loaded onto graphics card correctly");
        }
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, mSquareVertexBufferObjectIDArray[1]);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(sIndices.Length * sizeof(int)), sIndices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        GL.GetBufferParameter(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, BufferParameterName.BufferSize, out sSize);

        if (sIndices.Length * sizeof(int) != sSize)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Index data not loaded onto graphics card correctly");
        }

        GL.VertexAttribPointer(vPositionLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 *
        sizeof(float), 0);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(vColourLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 *
        sizeof(float), 3 * sizeof(float));

        //GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vColourLocation);
        //GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionLocation);

        //triangle
        float[] tVertices = new float[] { -0.8f, 0.8f, 0.4f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.6f,
                                          -0.6f, -0.4f, 0.4f, -0.2f, 0.5f, 1.0f,
                                          0.2f, 0.2f, 0.4f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

        uint[] tIndices = new uint[] { 0, 1, 2 };


        //GL.GenVertexArrays(2, mVertexArrayObjectIDs);
        GL.BindVertexArray(mVertexArrayObjectIDs[0]);

        GL.GenBuffers(2, mTriangleVertexBufferObjectIDArray);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, mTriangleVertexBufferObjectIDArray[0]);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(tVertices.Length * sizeof(float)), tVertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        int size;
        GL.GetBufferParameter(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, BufferParameterName.BufferSize, out size);

        if (tVertices.Length * sizeof(float) != size)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Vertex data not loaded onto graphics card correctly");
        }
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, mTriangleVertexBufferObjectIDArray[1]);

        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(tIndices.Length * sizeof(int)), tIndices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        GL.GetBufferParameter(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, BufferParameterName.BufferSize, out size);

        if (tIndices.Length * sizeof(int) != size)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Index data not loaded onto graphics card correctly");
        }

        GL.VertexAttribPointer(vPositionLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 *
        sizeof(float), 0);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(vColourLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 *
        sizeof(float), 3 * sizeof(float));

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vColourLocation);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionLocation);

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);

        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        GL.BindVertexArray(mVertexArrayObjectIDs[1]);
        GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 6, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

        GL.BindVertexArray(mVertexArrayObjectIDs[0]);
        GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 3, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

        GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        this.SwapBuffers();
    }

    protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnUnload(e);
        GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        GL.DeleteVertexArrays(2, mVertexArrayObjectIDs);
        GL.DeleteBuffers(2, mTriangleVertexBufferObjectIDArray);
        GL.DeleteBuffers(2, mSquareVertexBufferObjectIDArray);
        GL.UseProgram(0);
        mShader.Delete();
    }
}
```

}

EDIT: [image: Here is what it looks like]

Comment: care to add a screen shot of your wrong triangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not using the shader after I loaded it.

Added 
        GL.UseProgram(mShader.ShaderProgramID);

After shader loading code.

Answer (score 1):

You draw with

```
GL.BindVertexArray(mVertexArrayObjectIDs[1]);
GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan, 4, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
```

however the indices you use are for `PrimitiveType.Triangles`

Replace that with

```
GL.BindVertexArray(mVertexArrayObjectIDs[1]);
GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 6, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
```

Comment: What do you mean ? I am using the tIndices? Why is that when I bind them on line 62? GL.BindVertexArray(mVertexArrayObjectIDs[1]);

Comment: @Minanda Those indices are meant to be drawn with PrimitiveType.Triangles.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I previously had that indices as {0,1,2,3}; which made it triangle fan. 

I changed that to try it with triangle. Neither works they both give the same result.